# .NET webbrowser - documentcompleted not responding correctly

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer, browser

i am doing this:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.IndexOf("Negative Orders") != -1)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(@"http://............somepage");

        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("finished loading");
    }
}
```

something very weird is happening. it is succesfully entering the `IF STATEMENT`; however once it executes the `webBrowser.Navigate`, it enter the `while`, and after the while it simply returns. **it does not do the messagebox at all.**

what is going on here?

Comment: Look at `DocumentText` in the debugger.

Comment: @slaks shabsi i reworded it thank u

Comment: What happens if you place the MessageBox before the while loop?

Comment: @herrow: you know the webbrowser control is part of .NET and not part of C#, right?

Comment: @evan if before then works fine

Comment: @herrow: It seems that the application is "stuck" in the while loop. Why not capture the Navigating event instead of using the while loop?

Comment: @evan i debugged it and it is not stuck in the loop

Comment: debug->break, are webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted and Application.DoEvents still on the call stack? WebBrowserReadyState.Complete is not the only navigation result, the navigation can end with error (e.g. a PDF viewer or doanload manager took over the navigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like an exception is occurring.  Try putting the whole thing in a try catch and breaking when an exception occurs

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.IndexOf("Negative Orders") != -1)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(@"http://............somepage");

            while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            MessageBox.Show("finished loading");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this, there is no exception, its just that nothing happens at all

Comment: I need some more context here, then.  Are you using WebBrowser on the main GUI thread in a winforms app?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your message box is not being called because your code is still in the `Application.DoEvents();` section deep down your call stack. It is probably waiting for you to leave the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` method to invoke the next `DocumentCompleted` handler and finally set the `ReadyState` to `Complete`.

I don't recommend using `Application.DoEvents();` at all, but specially not inside `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted`.